# How to see if a keybinding is used in any mode?

Tags: key-bindings, help, keystrokes

For example, I once set `<C-j>` as `<C-x>`, only to find out `<C-j>` is used for `org-forward-heading-same-level` in org-mode.

I know `<C-h> k` shows a keybinding's usage *in current mode*. However, how could I know if a keybinding is used in *any* mode, so that I can safely set it to whatever I like without accidentally breaking anything?